# Programmatically enable Auto-approval for permission requests on non-community site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to auto approve permission requests on non-community sites ?
Regards
Nigel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is such an api -  SPAccessRequests.ChangeRequestStatus in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.

This can be put into a timer job which can then automatically approve Access Requests by calling SPAccessRequests.ChangeRequestStatus for each Access Request it finds in the Access Request list with a status of "Pending".

Found - thanks to Reflector.

Regards

Nigel

Answer (score 2):

**Is it possible to auto approve permission requests on non-community sites ?**

As a short answer , No

**Enable auto approval** feature is only available for Community Site collection.

[image]

**Note:**

The “Auto-Approval for permission request” section only appears when your community is a site collection and not a sub-site! So, if you need this functionality, make sure you create your community as a Site Collection!

For more details check

- [Manage community membership](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-community-membership-977a6824-1d56-48bd-95e3-dddce4162fc7?CorrelationId=287ee9cb-df8f-4aca-b6c4-deadaa9751e1&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102925051)
- [Community Site Missing Enable Auto Approval](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/10/community-site-missing-enable-auto-approval.html)